# WPF CollectionChanged Event OldItems.Count

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an ObservableCollection and I attach to the CollectionChanged event:

```
void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
        {
            int id = -1 * i;
            DocumentWatchList d = (DocumentWatchList)e.NewItems[i];
            d.UID = id;
            _dataDc.DocumentWatchLists.InsertOnSubmit(d);
        }
    }
    else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
        {
            DocumentWatchList d = (DocumentWatchList)e.OldItems[i];
            _dataDc.DocumentWatchLists.DeleteOnSubmit(d);
        }
    }
    _dataDc.SubmitChanges();
}
```

My collection is bound to a datagrid, and the viewmodel code (above) gets called as expected.  When I select multiple rows and hit delete, I expect that the OldItems collection will contain the number of rows that I had selected (n).  however, what actually happens is that the event gets called n times, and each time the OldItems collection count is 1.  So under what conditions will the OldItems collection contain more than 1 item?  Is this behavior coming from the datagrid control, or rather is it the way ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged is meant to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, ObservableCollection doesn't support a NotifyCollectionChanged event with multiple items.

You can do this:

```
OnCollectionChanged(
    new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
        NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, singleItem));
```

But not this: (you'll get a `NotSupportedException`)

```
 OnCollectionChanged(
    new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
        NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, multipleItems));
```

I can't think of any scenario where e.OldItems.Count would be greater than 0.

[Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/16/listcollectionviewcollectionview-doesnt-support-notifycollectionchanged-with-multiple-items.aspx) is a good article about it, where someone actually implemented the handling of multiple items themselves, for performance purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the interface that observable collection offers to you, you already know what you will get :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Basically it does not offer any way to insert or remove multiple items at once. So this effectively means that you can clear the whole collection, but if you need to say remove 2 items while there are 6 in the collection, you will have to remove them one by one. Which is what the datagrid will do in your case , but suppose you were to implement you own datagrid, you would be forced to do it the same way.

To make the answer complete, I must add that there is a way to get multiple items in the deleted list, but only by clearing the collection.

Replacing an item in the collection is also possible, by using the index operator, you can even replace an item with itself. I' ve tried this and this works, you will get the same item in the deleted collection and inserted collection in that case, but also here one by one.

You can of course create you own implementation of observable collection that would solve these issues. But I think you would need a different implementation of datagrid too, that would use your custom new bulk insert or bulk delete operations.